# SQL query for recipes that can be made from collection of ingredients

Tags: sql, database, recipe

I have a database that has a table of Ingredients I and a table of Recipes R.  The two tables have a many-to-many relationship, as one recipes uses many ingredients and one ingredient is used in many recipes.  I have a third cross-reference table that uses the [cross-reference validation pattern](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/01/table-design-patterns-cross-reference.html) to enforce my many-to-many relationship, and is done using string foreign keys (instead of integers).

Assuming I have a collection of ingredients C outside of my database, how can I query Recipe table R for every recipe that can be made using ONLY the list of ingredients supplied in C?

**Other things to consider**

1) Speed will (of course) be a concern eventually, but correctness is what I'm stuck on at the moment.

2) The collection of ingredients C might be very large (~100 ingredients).

Any answers or even just pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Alec

Comment: @Chandu, I haven't figured out any of that yet, I'm just working on this system as a hobby so I haven't laid out any specifications yet.  For now, you can just assume the current stable MySQL 5.5.25 .  But really, any answer you can provide I will try and port back to MySQL (or whatever DB I decide to use)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to write:

```
select ...
  from R
 where ID not in
        ( select R_ID
            from RI
           where I_ID not in
                  ( select I_ID
                      from C
                  )
        )
;
```

That is: start with `C`. Select all recipe–ingredient cross-references where the ingredient is *not* in `C`. This gives you the set of all recipes that *cannot* be made using only ingredients in `C`. Then, select all recipes that aren't in that set.

Comment: Good catch on my answer.  I read the question to fast.  I missed the point about only recipes that can be made with ONLY those ingredients.